# Powershell script to run program as admin

Tags: powershell

I have a ps1-script to start a program as an admin

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" -workingdirectory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\" -Verb RunAs;
```

however I don't have admin priviledges on my network account and when I run the script the opening prompt suggests to use network account. I would like to either input the admin pw straight to read-host and start program with local\admin or force prompt to change the the suggested user to "local\admin" so I only have to enter password.

Currently I have to push "More choises" > "Choose a different account" > write ".\admin".

I have tried:

```
$pw = read-host -assecurestring "pw"
$pp=new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "local\admin",$pw
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe' -Credential $pp -ArgumentList '-verb runas' -workingdirectory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\'
```

this however prompts me that "this task requires the application to have elevated permissions." and when I click "Restart under different credentials" nothing happens.

Comment: Sounds like when you launch powershell you need to right-click "run as administratror"

Comment: Yes I know that I can achieve the admin privileges with that. What I'm trying to achieve is not to need to use right click since I have win10 and I would need to select also more and then run as administrator. However the same result is obtained with the first line of code I posted.
The thing is that I would love to change the user prompt asks the password for.

Comment: when you don't want to type in some passwaord use credentials

Comment: Well if you would have read the code I posted in the second part there is the -Credential-tag used but it's still not working as it should be.

Comment: If you are asking if you can bypass the confirmation prompt that appears, the answer is no.

Comment: Okay if that's not possible then I'm looking for possibility to force prompt to change user from mydomain\basicuser to local\admin so I don't have to manually change it everytime.